# Como pegar o evento de scroll da tabela?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<table id="tab-grid">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

e preciso acionar a trigger javascript abaixo ao descer o scroll:

`$('.k-pager-refresh').trigger('click');`

Seja com javascript puro ou com jquery, como posso capturar o evento do scroll?

Comment: pode usar `$('#tab-grid').on('scroll', function() {  .... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#tab-grid').on('scroll', function() {
  $('.k-pager-refresh').trigger('click');
});
```

O problema dessa abordagem é que sempre vai disparar o click quando fizer um scroll (mudar a posição da página).

Uma possível solução para isso é controlar onde vai fazer o trigger.
Ex, no fim da página:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', () => {
  let tamanhoPagina = document.body.scrollHeight                         
  if(Math.round(document.documentElement.scrollTop) == tamanhoPagina) {
    // continua
  }
})
```